# JavaScript - multi-line textbox in prompt()?

Tags: javascript, prompt

Is there anyway to make the textbox/input box in `prompt` multiline?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, browsers only allow single-line input for `prompt()`. <strike>However, with a simple change to the jQuery Alert Dialogs library you could get multi-line input there. Take `jquery.alerts.js`, look for `<input type="text" size="30" id="popup_prompt" />` and replace it by `<textarea rows="5" cols="30" id="popup_prompt"></textarea>`. That should do to have a multi-line input field show up when calling `jPrompt()`.</strike>

**Edit**: As Mulletfingers999 points out in a comment, jQuery Alert Dialogs have been deprecated in favor of [jQuery UI dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/). There you can also show a "modal" dialog, that dialog can have arbitrary content however - meaning that a `<textarea>` tag is possible if you want  multi-line input.

Comment: For new viewers: the plugin has been archived, the developer recommends jQuery UI's [dialog widget](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: would love to avoid jquery since I'm using this as a simple javascript bookmarklet.

Comment: @Wyatt8740: Then you have to reimplement the functionality - overlay the page with your layer and add prompt content to it. Not entirely trivial unfortunately.

Comment: @WladimirPalant Just realized you're the 7-zip author. Thanks :) Also, I have done it using `document.open()`,`document.write()`, and the `<script>` tag. Huge pain, but it works.

Comment: @Wyatt8740: No, I have nothing to do with 7-zip.

Comment: @WladimirPalant Hmmt,here's some project you worked on that I use a lot (i recognize the name). Wonder what that'd be. (edit: oh god it's adblock. sorry)

Comment: I'm also using this as a bookmarklet. Shame I've now got to go reinvent the wheel in the guise of saving me click + drag copy + paste time

Answer (score 4):

Use \n encased in double quotes ("\n")

```
prompt("This\nis\nmultiline");
```

Comment: Alex, I mean `textbox` as input box.

Comment: In that case, no. The prompt is a native browser object and as such isn't directly editable. You'd be better off creating your own using jQuery or something similar :-)

Comment: Does not work, they get stripped out

Answer (score 3):

For pretty much any user-facing web application these days, you're going to want to avoid using clunky old dialogs like `alert()` and `prompt()`.  Almost any library you're using should have a much better answer.  jquery would be fine as others have said.  It would also be good to think of how you might eliminate a need for modality by designing a more clever interface.

"Interestingly", in Firefox they are already using XUL and reinventing a lot of user interface based on that (instead of relying on the "common dialogs" of the underlying OS).  There's a template for modal dialogs in [/source/toolkit/components/prompts/content/tabprompts.xml](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/prompts/content/tabprompts.xml#25):

```
<vbox anonid="infoContainer" align="center" pack="center" flex="1">
    <description anonid="info.title" class="info.title" hidden="true" />
    <description anonid="info.body" class="info.body"/>
</vbox>

<row anonid="loginContainer" hidden="true" align="center">
    <label anonid="loginLabel" value="&editfield0.label;" control="loginTextbox"/>
    <textbox anonid="loginTextbox"/>
</row>

<row anonid="password1Container" hidden="true" align="center">
    <label anonid="password1Label" value="&editfield1.label;" control="password1Textbox"/>
    <textbox anonid="password1Textbox" type="password"/>
</row>

<row anonid="checkboxContainer" hidden="true">
    <spacer/>
    <checkbox anonid="checkbox"/>
</row>
```

What they do is just hide the elements of the UI that they don't need.  In the case of a call to `prompt`, they re-use the user name field and keep the password and checkbox elements hidden.  You can see this happening in [/source/toolkit/components/prompts/src/CommonDialog.jsm#52](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/prompts/src/CommonDialog.jsm#52):

```
case "prompt":
  this.numButtons = 2;
  this.iconClass  = ["question-icon"];
  this.soundID    = Ci.nsISound.EVENT_PROMPT_DIALOG_OPEN;
  this.initTextbox("login", this.args.value);
  // Clear the label, since this isn't really a username prompt.
  this.ui.loginLabel.setAttribute("value", "");
  break;
```

Since it's more or less HTML, the only question is what the non-standard tag `<textbox>` means for the user interface.  The XUL controls documentation informs us that it's only a one-line entry, you would need `<textarea>` for more:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_controls

I thought it would be "fun" to look at the implementation in Chromium on top of GTK too.  After a bit of digging through the circuitous wrappers of WebKit, I did manage to find [chromium/src/chrome/browser/ui/gtk/js_modal_dialog_gtk.cc](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/browser/ui/gtk/js_modal_dialog_gtk.cc?revision=95628&content-type=text%2Fplain), specifically this part:

```
// Adjust content area as needed.  Set up the prompt text entry or
// suppression check box.
if (ui::MessageBoxFlags::kIsJavascriptPrompt == dialog_->dialog_flags()) {
  GtkWidget* content_area =
      gtk_dialog_get_content_area(GTK_DIALOG(gtk_dialog_));
  GtkWidget* text_box = gtk_entry_new();
  gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(text_box),
      UTF16ToUTF8(dialog_->default_prompt_text()).c_str());
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(content_area), text_box, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
  g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(gtk_dialog_), kPromptTextId, text_box);
  gtk_entry_set_activates_default(GTK_ENTRY(text_box), TRUE);
}
```

The text_box is created with `gtk_entry_new()` and the [GTK documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkEntry.html) states that `GtkEntry` is *"A single line text entry field"*.  For multi-line entry you would have to use `GtkTextView`:

http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkTextView.html

So there's your answer not just of "can you?" but the smoking guns of why you can't (in a couple of popular browser implementations.)  Unless there's a way to override that XUL in Firefox with an extension of some kind, which there may well be!  I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader.  :P

Comment: `<textbox>` can be [both multi-line and single-line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/textbox). Here it is a single-line input however because the `multiline` attribute is missing. Note that the common dialogs you found are irrelevant for the web as of Firefox 4 - they have been replaced by tab-modal dialogs that are implemented elsewhere (but along the same lines).

Comment: @Wladimir: Thanks for reading over it. I will point out that as of August 2011 Firefox 3.6 is still 30.28% of Firefox users so not "irrelevant for the web" yet. I take no responsibility for omissions in the XUL docs, which I linked. Was my first time digging into these codebases, for my own curiosity under the guise of answering a question with more than a glib "no you can't." I spent a little time poking around to try and make an extension that overrode the prompt today, but decided to try doing it in Firefox 6 and it seems that most of the "how to make an extension" tutorials have rotted.

Comment: The docs you linked to list both `<textbox>` and `<textbox multiline="true"/>`. :) Anyway, the tutorials should still be fine - as far as regular XUL overlays go nothing changed much. But you won't get too far with the overlays because the relevant code moved into an XBL binding ([tabprompts.xml](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/prompts/content/tabprompts.xml#41)) and changing that one is quite a bit more complicated.

Comment: Oh multiline, how you taunt me.  Y'know, I did do a bunch of research and then after the fact go back and find documents I thought were the same, but might have been different after all.  Either way it gets confusing if it strongly implies one differentiating characteristic and then later throws in a "...but!"

Comment: true, `prompt()` is antiquated - but for bookmarklets it's super-simple to use. (also note that in 2015 unfortunately Mozilla decided to deprecate XUL - a real tragedy).