# How to inject custom HTML into a page using a bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I imagine a bookmarklet that lets the user paste an arbitrary piece of HTML onto a page.

Something like

```
var html = prompt("Please enter HTML");
$(document).append(html); // jQuery-like syntax - just illustrating what I want to achieve
```

`prompt()` isn't well suited for this, because it's a one liner - I want to paste multiple lines. This [isn't really possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255444/javascript-multi-line-textbox-in-prompt) in straight up js. You could make a bookmarklet that creates a new div, lets you input HTML in that div, and then inject the content of the div as raw HTML.

Before building it, I'd like to know if this has been done before?

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish (what is the real problem to be solved here)?  It's possible using JS to make any changes you want to the current page, but you have to know exactly what you're trying to change and how to find where to insert the new content.  You can't use `document.write()` once the document has already been loaded because that will first clear the current document and then start writing.  You would use other DOM manipulation functions like `createElement()` and `appendChild()` or `insertBefore()`.

Comment: In addition to the functions that @jfriend00 names, you'd probably create a div and then use `div.innerHTML = html`.

Comment: Hm.  You could add a new div immediately preceding the final </body> tag that contained a textbox and button... and have the button call code to rewrite the div to contain just the contents of the textbox.  I've never seen anything quite like that, but it should be possible, and not even that hard.

Comment: @jfriend00 - fixed `document.write` in my example. What I'm trying to achieve is exactly what I stated in the question - a generic bookmarklet that lets me inject any HTML, given as fresh input. (It's just a debugging tool we need). I know how to do this, I'm just wondering whether it's done already before I code this up myself.