# window.prompt multiple line input JavaScript CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to find a way to make something equivalent to `window.prompt`, but which allows multiple lines of input.

I could create my own using a div with `z-index` containing a `textArea`, but I am hoping there is something out there in jQuery or a plugin that would be more elegant.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about a jQuery dialog? http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255444/javascript-multi-line-textbox-in-prompt

Comment: Thanks both, I will refer to 7255444 (about jquery dialog).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) to do that.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/RBKaZ/

Using this HTML

```
<div id="dialog">
    <p>Please enter your name</p>
    <textarea id="name"></textarea>
</div>
<label>Name entered: </label>
<label id="nameentered"></label>
<br />
<input type="button" id="open" value="Open Dialog" />
```

And this jQuery:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: { 
        Ok: function() {
            $("#nameentered").text($("#name").val());
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$("#open").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```