# How to put prompt alert and confirm together?

Tags: javascript, prompt

How to put prompt, alert and confirm together?
I got this already, but i want to add an confirm box after the prompt and alert..
Can someone please help?

```
<script>

var name = prompt('What is your name?')

alert('Your name is ' + name )
```

Comment: By the way: I want a confirm box with the name in it.

Comment: Then do the same thing you are doing with `alert()` but replace `alert` with `confirm`. If you are asking how to make them all one box, you can't, at least not with the native dialogs

Comment: `How to put prompt alert and confirm together?` - I agree they belong together, but never in a public facing web page :p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - multi-line textbox in prompt()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255444/javascript-multi-line-textbox-in-prompt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Patrick suggested in the comments, you need to use the Confirm instead of Alert, clicking Confirm OK will give you value: true i.e.

```
<script>

var name = prompt('What is your name?');

var confirm = confirm('Your name is ' + name );

if(confirm === true){

 //Your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    var name = prompt("Please enter your name", "XYZ");

    if (name != null) {
       alert('Your name is ' + name )


    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It will ask your name and comes in alert after giving name to prompt.